# declaring a variable with only 2 decimal points in C

Tags: c, math, numbers, decimal, fixed-point

I am trying to declare a variable eLon with only 1 decimal place so that if I have the code:

```
elon=359.8
printf("eLon = %f\n",eLon);
```

and the output will be

```
eLon = 359.8
```

However the output I get is:

```
eLon = 359.7999999.
```

How I know that I could modify the printf so that it would be:

```
printf(eLon is %0.1f\n",eLon);
```

to get the desired result.  This is NOT what I want to do.  I just want the variable itself to only have one decimal place so that it equals 359.8 not 359.7999999, since this is critical for any computations I make.   Do you know how I should modify my code to get the desired result.  I tried doing what was suggested in other inquiries but it did not work for example the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int endLonn;
    float endLon,eLon;
    endLon=359.8;
    endLonn=359.8*10;
    printf("%d is endLonn\n",endLonn);
    eLon= endLonn / 10;
    printf("elon is %f\n",eLon);
}
```

gives me the output:

```
elon is 359.00000000
```

Again this is also not what I am looking for.  I want elon is 359.8.  If you could help me tweak my code to get the desired result that would be great.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not possible, unless you write your own decimal floating point type.

Comment: Could cheat, treat it as a string, split it up using decimal point as separator, get the first part up to the decimal point, then get the first digit after the decimal point, add 1 to it if greater than 5, and concatenate the string together?

Comment: The last two lines should work if you do `eLon = (float)endLonn / 10f;` Right now `endLonn / 10` gets truncated to 359 *before* being assigned to `eLon`.

Comment: Posting the higher level goal would help rather than the contradictory "declaring a variable with only 2 decimal points" vs. "declare a variable eLon with only 1 decimal place".  In other words, describe the need for "this is critical for any computations", so the answers will address your larger issue.

Comment: When converting a floating point number to a  nearby `int`, use `eLon= (int) round(endLonn / 10);`

Comment: I see this still open.  Any particular concern not being addressed?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of trying to cheat double or float and printf, you can use fixed point arithmetic. In the particular case of your example you will express variable in 0.1s of it's original value:

```
int in_10s;
in_10s=3598;
printf("My fixed point variable "
       "represents %d.%01d value\n",
         in_10s/10, abs(in_10s % 10));
```

In general case of n decimal places, the format to printf should be %d.%0**n**d, where n=log_10(scaling_factor^-1), and scaling factor is interpreted like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: Using an `int` is fine with operations like `+ - *`, compare, print.  Yet using `int` with`/`, interest rates, `pow()` and watch for overflow, it rapidly has its problems too.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not a floating point number but a fixed point decimal, which is for example available in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) as `decimal`. [c](/questions/tagged/c) doesn't give you that. There are two "typical" approaches to roll your own:

1. Use a plain `int` and just have the decimal point at some position *by convention*. e.g. your value would be `int elon=3598`.
2. Use a `struct` with two ints, one for the whole number part and one for the amount of tenths (or hundredths, thousandths, ...)

In both cases, you will need to implement your own logic for output. The simple approach using a plain `int` at least lets you use basic arithmetics as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can't *declare* a variable to hold only one decimal figure. The only native types able to represent non-integer values are floating point types, on which any arithmetic operation which yield a value of the same nature. Floating point types cannot be limited to a fixed number of decimal figures.

In order to achieve what you are asking for, you have to either **implement** such behavior or use an existing implementation of what is called *fixed-point airthmetic*.

A pretty complete introduction can be found in [Wikipedia's Fixed-Point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) entry. At the end you will find a couple of libraries implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want the variable itself to only have one decimal place so that it equals 359.8 not 359.7999999,

You should use double:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
    int endLonn;
    double endLon,eLon;
    endLon=359.8;
    endLonn=359.8*10;
    printf("%d is endLonn\n",endLonn);
    eLon = endLonn / 10;
    printf("elon is %.1lf\n%.1lf",eLon,endLon);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 3598 is endLonn
> elon is 359.0
> 359.8
> ```

Comment: It depends on OPs need, but specifically asking for a variable with a defined number of decimal places might have a good reason. E.g. working with values representing amounts of money, you **never** want to use a floating-point type, no matter what precision.

Comment: Personal I almost never use float (and I never recommend it, only if he's 100% sure about float need), but i know that it is at some point needed.

Comment: that's unrelated and I consider `float` utterly useless, given all literals are `double` by default. I was talking about *any* floating-point type.

Comment: @Felix Palmen What is wrong with using [decimal floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) for money?

Comment: @chux making it explicit then: *any of C's floating-point types*. And I don't think you want to implement *this* yourself.

Comment: @Felix Palmen C floating point types are not specified to be binary based.  C specifies `FLT_RADIX`, the "radix of exponent representation" which often has the value of 2 but implementations have used 10 and 16. Regardless of base, Given I have successfully created and used working financial code - to the penny - do not agree with "...representing amounts of money, you never want to use a floating-point type" .  YMMV